# Windows XP not showing Application Data folder

Tags: windows-xp

My friend using Vista goes to his AppData folder and sees the folder ".test" but when I go to mine on Windows XP... I do not see ".test" while other Application Data folders show. Funny thing is... the applet DOES recognize the ".test" folder on my machine even though it's not appearing in Application Data... weird. Maybe it's because it has a dot in front of test? I don't know.

Before you ask, yes, he does have "Show Hidden Files/Folders" check on.

Comment: What "applet" are you talking about? And there are several folders for Application Data on Windows, and they are in different places in XP and Vista. What is the exact path where you expect to see the folder? Is it marked as Hidden? Does Windows Explorer show hidden files and folders?

Comment: Yes, he said he has "Show Hidden Files/Folders" marked ON... and the folder is in Application Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on the specific applet you're using, but if it behaves in the way you're expecting, you can try typing each of the following into the Start → Run dialog box on your machine to check the various folders it might be in:

- `%AppData%`
- `%AllUsersAppData%`
- `%CSIDL_AppData%`
- `%CSIDL_Local_AppData%`